# Milne-Thompson Theorem with a Vortex

Tags: complex-analysis, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

I'm doing a problem related with Milne-Thompson theorem which tells that: "A cylinder of radius $a$ is immersed in a counter-clockwise whirlpool, which we model here as a potential vortex of intensity $\Gamma$ whose center is at a distance $L$ from the axis of the cylinder". First it is necessary to find the potential associated to the vortex which I got that:

$f(z) =-\dfrac{i\Gamma}{2\pi}\ln(z+L)$

The Milne-Thomson theory says that:

$f_{c}(z)=f(z)+\bar{f} \left ( \dfrac{a^2}{z} \right)$

So it is necessary to get the complex conjugate of the function. My problem is that I get two different results $\bar{f}(z)=\dfrac{i\Gamma}{2\pi}\ln(z+L)$ (applying properties of conjugates that I saw and through Wolfram) and $\bar{f}(z) =-\dfrac{i\Gamma}{2\pi}\ln(z+L)$ (using $z=re^{i\theta}$, solving and then applying the conjugate definition). So I'm doing something wrong in one of the methods and I would like to know what is the correct solution. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logarithmic function is multi-valued in the complex plane, which makes any answer correct only  up to an integer multiple of $2\pi i$, unless one somehow specifies the branch to use.

Neither of two answers can be correct, because they present a *holomorphic* function, while $\bar f$ is *anti-holomorphic*.

Suppose we use the principal branch of logarithm, which is real on the positive real axis. The reflection principle says that $\overline{f(z)} = f(\bar z)$. Hence,

$$\overline{f(z)} =\dfrac{i\Gamma}{2\pi}\ln(\bar z+L)$$

For other branches, there may be $+2\pi i k$ with some integer $k$.