# Trouble completing derivation using Milne-Thompson Circle Theorem with a Vortex

Tags: complex-analysis, physics, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics, several-complex-variables

I am having trouble finishing the derivation using the Milne-Thompson Circle Theorem (MTCT) for a potential flow with a vortex at a location $\zeta_v$.

My understanding of the MTCT is that the complex potential $w_v$ (with subscript $v$ for vortex) transforms accordingly when a circle is present,

$$w_{vc}(\zeta)=w_v(\zeta)+\overline{w_v\left(\frac{a^2}{\overline{\zeta}}\right)}$$ or equivalently $$w_{vc}(\zeta)=w_v(\zeta)+\overline{w_v}\left(\frac{a^2}{\zeta}\right).$$

My complex velocity is $$w_v(\zeta)=\frac{\Gamma}{2\pi i}\ln(\zeta-\zeta_v)$$ where $\zeta_v$ is the position of the vortex. I know the final complex velocity with the circle $w_{vc}$ is $$w_{vc}(\zeta)=\frac{\Gamma}{2\pi i}\left[\ln(\zeta-\zeta_v)-\ln\left(\zeta-\frac{a^2}{\overline{\zeta_v}}\right)+\ln(\zeta)\right].$$ The furthest I've been able to get is the following, $$\frac{\Gamma}{2\pi i}\left[\ln(\zeta-\zeta_v)-\ln\left(a^2\left(\frac{1}{\zeta}-\frac{1}{\zeta_v}\right)\right)\right]$$ and I'm not sure if I made a mistake or if I just can't figure what to do with this form of the equation.

I think some of my confusion may be because of notation. My textbook by Batchelor says the MTCT uses $\overline{w\left(\frac{a^2}{\zeta}\right)}$ where elsewhere it is $\overline{w\left(\frac{a^2}{\overline{\zeta}}\right)}=\overline{w}\left(\frac{a^2}{\zeta}\right)$ which I guess are identical. Although, the answers to these two questions ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694816/milne-thompson-theorem-with-a-vortex), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203869/milne-thomson-circle-theorem-proof)) seem to contradict that but I'm probably misunderstanding something.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This answer should clear up the notation: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2189004/148510

Comment: @RRL do you know of any text, or other resource I can find this material for a citation?

Comment: Theoretical Hydrodynamics by Milne-Thompson would be a start.

Comment: @RRL I have that. I meant something regarding the complex variable notation.

Comment: As you saw Batchelor does not explain it properly. The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milne-Thomson_circle_theorem) does.  The notation $\bar{f}$ means the conjugate to a complex-valued function of a complex variable, which as you discovered is not the same thing as the complex conjugate of the value $\bar{f(z)}$.  I'll look for another reference to that terminology.

Comment: Thank you. I also use the text from Kundu, but I don't think they even address the circle theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reconcile the last term, but here's what I have so far:

$w_{vc}(\zeta) = w_v(\zeta)+\bar{w}_v(\frac{a^2}{\zeta})$

$=\frac{\Gamma}{2\pi i}[ln(\zeta-\zeta_v)-ln(\frac{a^2}{\zeta}-\bar{\zeta}_v)]$

Since:

$ln(\frac{a^2}{\zeta}-\bar{\zeta}_v)=ln(\zeta-\frac{a^2}{\bar{\zeta}_v})+ln(-\frac{\bar{\zeta}_v}{\zeta})=ln(\zeta-\frac{a^2}{\bar{\zeta}_v})+ln(-\bar{\zeta}_v)-ln(\zeta)$

We have that:

$w_{vc}(\zeta) = \frac{\Gamma}{2\pi i}[ln(\zeta-\zeta_v)-ln(\zeta-\frac{a^2}{\bar{\zeta}_v})+ln(\zeta)-ln(i\bar{\zeta}_v)-\frac{i\pi}{2}]$

Maybe the last terms go away because it's constant, and these are periodic functions? I also could have messed up somewhere; I'm not the best with complex logarithms.

Comment: I believe this is correct as adding an arbitrary constant to the potential does not change the complex velocity $\frac{dw}{d\zeta}$

Comment: I think that makes sense, I had forgot about the derivative.